# Android Intent : Always get resultCode = 0

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-intent

I'm trying to get the result of intent between 2 activities but something is wrong because I always get a resultCode = 0 in initial activity:

**Code inside CarsFragment.kt**

```
private fun startAddCarActivity() {
    val intent = Intent(context, AddCarActivity::class.java)
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    // ALWAYS GET requestCode = 1, resultCode = 0 and data = null !!
}
```

**AddCarActivity.kt:**

```
private fun startCarsNavigationActivity() {
    intent.putExtra("car", car)
    setResult(1, intent)
    finish()
}
```

**Problem:**

I always get requestCode = 1, resultCode = 0 and data = null in CarsFragment.kt

Where is the problem ?

Comment: `override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
  if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
  //get your data here and use it  
}`
}

Comment: Replace setResult(1, intent) with setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent) on  AddCarActivity and check resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK on carFragment's onActivityResult.

Comment: @Shijil Always get the same : requestCode = 1, resultCode = 0 and data = null

Comment: What `launchMode` is in manifest for AddCarActivity?. Maybe it is starting in a different task, i believe there is a known problem in returning a result between diff tasks.

Comment: post your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Result code of 0 means `RESULT_CANCELED`. This can happen if the `Activity` you are launching is launched into a different task, or if the user presses the BACK key, or if the launched `Activity` decides to return `RESULT_CANCELED`.